# Chrome Extension Error: Error in invocation of pageAction.show

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So I'm working on a Chrome Extension to reload a page at regular intervals but I've found an error: `Error handling response: TypeError: Error in invocation of pageAction.show(integer tabId, optional function callback): No matching signature.`.

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Reloader",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Reloads pages.",
  "permissions": ["tabs", "declarativeContent", "storage"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "page_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/symbolsmall.png"
    }
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(tabs) {
    chrome.pageAction.show(tabs.id);
});
```

I did some console.logs and checked the docs for chrome.pageAction.show and the syntax checks out but the error persists. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message means you've passed an incorrect parameter. If you debug your code in [devtools for the background page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029), you'll see `tabs.id` is `undefined`. As you can see in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onActivated) the listener of onActivated receives an object with `tabId` and `windowId` inside:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {
  chrome.pageAction.show(activeInfo.tabId);
});
```

Note, if you plan on showing the page_action unconditionally like you do currently, there's no benefit in using page_action at all and you can simply switch to [browser_action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) which is enabled by default so you won't need to show() it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion with browser action, I'm new to extensions so I'm not great and your comment helped a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This error also occurs when you call a function in the callback parameter instead of passing it.

```
function foo(param){
  //do something
}


chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(foo(param)); //this will give you the error
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(foo); //this should work fine
```

Seems obvious but, I have made this error countless times. Hope it is helpful.